# Jquery mobile application doesn't load a new page in default android browser

Tags: jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile

I have created a list in jquery mobile which directs to some page on click. it is working fine in android emulator. But showing some strange behavior in android phone's default browser.
When i am clicking on list's item it directs me to another page but redirects back automatically. 
The URL in the browser remains the page to which list directs the user but the content remains the same as of previous page.

Please, somebody response. I am really stuck on this.

You can see the same problem in jquerymobile demo:
http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/index.html

I am opening this page in android-2.3 (tried in HTC and Samsung) , on clicking on list's item it directs me to another page but redirects back automatically. It doesn't happen always, but most of the times when clicking on list items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got my answer see:-
http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-mobile-true-browser-back-button-issue

Just you have to do following:-

```
$.extend(  $.mobile , {
hashListeningEnabled: false
});
```